# GitHub Actions Set Output - Assure Parallel Job Access is Safe

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, building-github-actions

I have configured my github actions which runs tests in parallel for different platforms. At the end of my tests I want the status to be saved to the outputs. Once all jobs complete I have another job that runs to send the results to a slack webhook.

I am having difficulty determining a method to save the output for multiple jobs and assuring there is no issues when they are running in parallel.

For example this is my code snippet

```
name: Test Notify

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        config:
          - name: 'Ubuntu 18.04'
            runner: 'ubuntu-18.04'
            id: 'u18'

          - name: 'Ubuntu 20.04'
            runner: 'ubuntu-20.04'

      fail-fast: false

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.runner }}

    outputs:
      # Prefer to have one general output I can append to
      global: ${{ steps.status.outputs.global }}

      # I can output to separate outputs but I rather have a single one as shown above
      u18: ${{ steps.status.outputs.u18 }}
      u20: ${{ steps.status.outputs.u20 }}

    steps:

      - name: Test Failure u18
        id: step1
        if: ${{ matrix.config.id == 'u18' }}
        run: |
          exit 1

      - name: Doing Step 2
        id: step2
        run: |
          echo "DO NOTHING"

      - name: Output Status
        id: status
        if: always()
        env:
          JOB_STATUS: "${{ job.status }}"
        run: |
          # This works, but is it safe since I have u18 and u20 running in parallel ?
          echo "${{ matrix.config.id }}=$JOB_STATUS" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

          # Is there a safe way to have a single status string that I add to, for example;
          # echo "global=${{ github_output.global}}$JOB_STATUS" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT


  webhook:
    needs: build
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-20.04'
    if: always()
    steps:
      - name: Send webhook update for all jobs
        env:
          JSON_RESULTS: "${{ toJSON(needs.build-and-test) }}"
        run: |
          # Will add code to properly send the information
          echo $JSON_RESULTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no easy way to reference all outputs of matrix jobs. Moreover combining it into a single output.

The issue is that only a single value is available for future jobs that need the `strategy.matrix` job’s output because even if the output is set by multiple matrix variations of the job, only one is retained.

For more detail, see the [Community discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/17245).

**TL;DR:**

There are several workarounds:

- defining separate outputs for a job with `strategy.matrix` by letting the job variations set different outputs

  - then process these outputs in a separate step that can provide single output for further steps
- use artifacts to store the matrix jobs' outputs and then post-process it ([discussioncomment-3814009](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/17245#discussioncomment-3814009))